# Outlook 2010 default email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there an easy way to pre-fill the email on all types of actions (new, reply, forward)? When I say easy, I mean not being harder than doing a new / reply at this point.

E.g. I use a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+M</kbd> now to open a new email dialog. Instead of having a blank mail, I'd like (at least body) to be pre-filled with some text.

I saw some ways to do it, such as:

- https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/02/20/create-email-templates-outlook/

however they are more a workaround than a solution, as they add other steps to the workflow, making it considerably more complex.

Comment: [Create a macro in Outlook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) that [crates a new email with your chosen text](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-a-new-message-using-vba/), then [assign it to a button](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm) and/or give it a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It is unclear what your definition of "easy" is. How about saving a pre-written email as a file outside of Outlook. Any time you want to use it, just double click and it opens the message as you saved it. I use these for all types of pre-formatted emails. If that will work for you, I can post instructions as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start filling out an email and save it as a template (.oft) then pin the template to the task bar. Now when you want to reply and use a certain response right click on outlook ( on the taskbar ) and select the template you want to use.